# Get image Fingerprint stm32f205 from Arduino

Tags: java, image, bitmap, arduino, fingerprint

Help, I got lost!

I'm using Waveshare's fingerprint stm32f205, which I connected to an Arduino Uno R3 and communicated with it via Java with the RXTXComm library.

I have managed to get the bytes of each request to the Arduino, but the drawback is that when I receive the bytes of the image of the trace, I cannot save them as Bitmap or JPG.

I was seeing that the data, before sending them as bytes, are integers without signs (0 to 255).

The bytes are stored in an array of Bytes and also in another array of integers.

Could you explain or tell me what algorithm should I use to convert bytes into an image?

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIVm1.png) indicates how to send the data of the image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To convert 8-bit grey array to RGB:

```
int[] greyArraySource = ...;

int[] rgbArray = new int[greyArraySource.length];
for(int i=0; i<greyArraySource.length; i++) {
    int color = (int)aImageData[i];
    if(color < 0)
    {
        color = 256 + color;
    }
    rgbArray[i] = Color.rgb(color,color,color);
}
```

After you could convert your RGB array to [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html):

```
// Initialize BufferedImage
int width = ...;
int height = ...;
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

// Set RGB array to the BufferedImage
BufferedImage.setRGB(0,0,BufferedImage.getWidth(),
    BufferedImage.getHeight(),rgbArray, 0, BufferedImage.getWidth());
```

Convert BuffuredImage to JPG:

```
File outputfile = new File("image.jpg");
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
```

It seems your image is in 4-bits so you need to change the convert. If you post array value, maybe I could check.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for replying @LaurentY, that's right, the image is in 4 bit.
Apply the code provided by you with a small modification.

```
imgS = cadena.split(",");
int[] rgbArray = new int[imgS.length];
            for(int i=0; i<imgS.length; i++) {
                int color = Integer.parseInt(imgS[i]);
                if(color < 0)
                {
                    color = 256 + color;
                }
                rgbArray[i] = new Color(color, color, color).getRGB();
            }
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(biWidth, biHeight,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            // Set RGB array to the BufferedImage
            bufferedImage.setRGB(0,0,bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(),rgbArray, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth());
            File outputfile = new File("D:\\finger.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LeerArduino.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

The result is this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2gIj.jpg).

Here I leave the values of the array in a txt [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0JgAONgdVc8S2J6ajlmR2hWZE0/view?usp=sharing). Each value separates them by comma.

See you!

Answer (score -1):

I have used recently this fingerprint module. My project on Matlab, I can extract fingerprint image. With serial port terminal program (i used CoolTerm) image data captured in text file with hex format seperated with space only.
Your image is not 140x140/2 bytes. In matlab scan your txt file, 124x148/2=9176 bytes. Further you may split this numbers to upper and lower nibbles(4 bit). Firstly you must convert these uint8 to 8 bit bytes or two digit hex's. My java knowledge is not well, but in matlab:

`fileID = fopen('Value.txt','r');
A=textscan(fileID,'%u8','Delimiter',','); %text file to matrix
YI=reshape(A{1,1},[62,148]); % image reshaped 
imshow(YI');`

With this code and your Value.txt file gives this [finger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfnFY.jpg)